# Apache mod_rewriting not finding any files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

OK, so we have a specific set of rewrites that we use on a number of sites due the file structure of our programming. It's never been a problem before until now.

For example, the rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^$ Pages/news.php
```

Instead of directing to `http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Pages/news.php` it is redirecting to `/path/to/file/public/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Pages/news.php` and it's 404-ing (`/path/to/file` being the actual path).

If anyone could shed any light as to why this is happening, or point me in the right direction then I would be eternally grateful.

I am running all of my script and files in a subfolder, there is another .htaccess file in the root folder which I have edited in at the bottom but it doesn't seem to contain anything that could be interfering.

If you require any further information on the server then let me know!

---

EDIT - Here are all my rewrites as requested.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ Pages/news.php  
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(0|1)/(.*).jpg?$ Classes/Image/timthumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/images/$4.jpg&h=$1&w=$2&zc=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(/)?$ Pages/archives.php?cat_id=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^archives/mon/([0-9]+)/yr/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ Pages/archives.php?mon=$1&yr=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)(/)?$ Pages/archives.php?cat_id=$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^archives/mon/([0-9]+)/yr/([0-9]+)(/)?$ Pages/archives.php?mon=$1&yr=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)(/)?$ Pages/article.php?art_id=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wedding-venues-catering-rss(/)?$ rss/rss.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Page-Error(/)?$ Pages/errorPage.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Page-Error
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Page-Error
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Page-Error
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Page-Error
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domain.com/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Page-Error
```

---

I also tried to reference the rewrites with absolute URL's, this worked of course, but they were just redirecting instead of rewriting as you might expect.

---

EDIT - This is the other .htaccess file in the root directory, which is part of their existing site.

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
redirect 301 /Cavendish.htm http://www.domain.com/
redirect 301 /grange.htm http://www.domain.com/
redirect 301 /restaurant/index.html http://www.domain.com/
redirect 301 /news/Save-money-by-booking-wedding-venues-in-Middlesex-at-off-peak-times.asp http://www.domain.com/
redirect 301 /news/default.asp http://www.domain.com/
```

---

EDIT - I thought this might be relevant.

The 404 error on the rewrite shows this path -

```
 /l/i/domain.com/public/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Pages/news.php
```

But.. if I edit news.php and request SCRIPT_FILENAME it gives me the path..

```
 /services/webpages/l/i/domain.com/public/wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Pages/news.php
```

My guess is that something is affecting the default path.

Furthermore I have tried basic rewrites at root level, but these also 404.

Comment: Can you tell us what the original request URI is, and also post the rest of your rules?

Comment: http://www.domain.com/news is the URI I am requesting, and technically it should rewrite to /Pages/news.php.

Comment: Also, just to mention that all the files, including the .htaccess, are in the /news subfolder.

Comment: @Danny Better update your question with htaccess rewrite rules and delete comments -- much easier to read = more interest to help :)

Comment: @LazyOne, thankyou for your tip, all done now :)

Comment: Try doing the most obvious -- adding the `[L]` flag at the end of rule. Quick scan shows nothing wrong here.

Comment: No luck there i'm afraid. None of the other rewrites work in the list either, which leads me to believe it's something on the server. But alas, my server knowledge is rather limited.

Comment: You say in your original question that "it's never been a problem before now" -- does that mean that at some point, at least some of these rules were working?

Comment: We integrate news systems onto clients websites, so these rules are used every time. So they have been working on an abundance of other domains and servers, but never on this one.

Comment: If nothing does not work then: 1) mod_rewrite may not be enabled (check Apache error log); 2) rewrite rules are not allowed to be placed in .htaccess -- apply `AllowOverride All` directive to website root folder (or globally, if local personal server). 3) Definitely check your server config.

Comment: 1) I've checked the phpinfo, and mod_rewrite is enabled.
2) The client has their full site operating at root level, and they have a few redirects in there, plus a rewrite rule to add www. when it's omitted - and that works.
3) My server experience is very limited, and the only file I have access to is their .htaccess file - which doesn't contain much. Have you got any ideas of what to look for and where to look for it?

Comment: With that little info I cannot give you any solid advice here except already mentioned. It could be something very simple .. but I cannot guess it out of nowhere. Try to debug rewrite module: `RewriteLogLevel 9` and see rewrite log.

Comment: As I understand (after re-reading whole question), this is located in a subfolder (files and this .htaccess file) .. and they still have some rules in .htaccess root file. possibly that file interfering with your rules. try rewrite debugging -- the best thing in such situation (if you can, of course). If you cannot do it on client's server try reproducing it on your own dev server and do it there.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. This has been working on our development server previously, so it is just their server. 

I will add their root .htaccess to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue has been solved.

As the server is hosted with BT Business I decided to email them to see if they could help.

A guy replied saying he had logged in to the server and modified the .htaccess and it now works fine.

He simply added the subfolder in front of the rewritten URL's.

IE:-

```
RewriteRule ^$ Pages/news.php
```

Became: -

```
RewriteRule ^$ wedding-venues-and-caterers-news/Pages/news.php
```

I am still unsure why the subdirectory is needed when the .htaccess file is inside that directory, my guess is it is something to do with their server settings.